# .Addpicture to Word Document: Invalid Property Assignment

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am trying add a picture to a MS-Word document using VBA from MS-Access.
It does work, but when I try to also set the position, I get a run-time error.

Here is the line of code that works.

```
objShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strCompleteImagePath, LinkToFile:=False
```

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191833.aspx), the syntax for `.AddPicture` is

```
expression .AddPicture(Filename, LinkToFile, SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

I tried:

```
objShapes.AddPicture strCompleteImagePath, True, True, 100, 100 , 70 , 70
```

and

```
objShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strCompleteImagePath, _
                     LinkToFile:=False, _
                     SaveWithDocument:=False, _
                     Left:=100, _
                     Top:=100, _
                     Width:=70, _
                     Height:=70
```

But I get error messages of "wrong number of augments or invalid property assignment"

Is there something I am blind to? Is this because of MS-Access?

I'm taking the path of a graphics file from an MS-Access database, opening up a MS-Word document, and inserting the image into the middle of the document ...that is why I need to set its position. Is there not a way to do this in one operation, as `.AddPicture` seems to promise?

Comment: can't you first insert it and then move it to the place that you want?

Comment: Unrelated, but when is a file path not a `String`? Consider using `path` instead of `strCompleteImagePath` (that procedure only deals with one single path, doesn't it?) - and read up on why *Systems Hungarian* notation is completely useless [**in this excellent article**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN example in the [`Shapes.AddPicture` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191833.aspx) is adding the picture to a *canvas item*, not to the *shapes* collection directly. Did you try that?

The description is pretty clear, too:

> Adds a picture **to a drawing canvas**. Returns a Shape object that represents the picture and adds it to the CanvasShapes collection.

```
Dim canvas As Shape
Set canvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=70, Height:=70)

Dim pic As Shape
Set pic = canvas.CanvasItems.AddPicture(FileName:=path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

Comment: Mat and Masoud, Thanks for the suggestions. And while I can now set the image in a different location, I am still not sure how to force it to be on a new page. I am not an expert on MS word objects. I  imagine I have to define a new range to the last page of my document, and then some how pass that info to the AddPicture method.?  * fyi, I tried making the top argument > 800 think that would force it to start on the next page ) .

Comment: @EdFnj Happy to see hear it worked! If you have a new question, mark this one as answered and ask a new question - but make sure you research about how to add a page to a Word document, and how to add a shape on a specific page first.